Azure function app not always send log to application insight
Background
A function app setup with application insight, and you can find some logs, so the setup should be valid
Issue
Log is not always showing up in application insight, the function app will write a file into storage account, so you can confirm it did run successfully and at what time, however you cannot found entry in application insight at the time it run.
Any comments or workaround (other methods to check the runs) are welcome

It's likely your application is 'samping' telemetry, where is only sends a % of events to App Insights.
You can disabled sampling in your host.json file like so:
{
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": false
      }
    }
  }
} 

For more information see the 'Configure Sampling' section at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/configure-monitoring?tabs=v2
Also see this similar question How to disable adaptive sampling in an Azure Function App

Thanks Phil, I have taken a look at this unfortunately it don't look related to me, coz in our case log will miss for days and we have some other Function App with same setting without any issue, however I will give it a try when I have the chances.
